# unlink/file_exists and file not found

Tags: php, file-exists, unlink

I have this code in my application, often run in race condition by severals users of my application

```
clearstatcache(TRUE, $filepath);
if(file_exists($filepath)) unlink($filepath);
```

But, for this line of code, I still have severals errors each day like

> unlink(file): No such file or
>   directory

Server run Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3. I know race problem, but think @ operator is just evil. I have first tried without any parameter for clearstatcache(), with the same error. 
How can I do it the correct way?

Comment: could you add a bit of your code please.

Comment: @experimentX but it's right there, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka well, i don't see any flaw in the code above, i guess

Comment: In this case the @ operator might not be too evil *awaits death by comments*. Depends on how critical this bit of code is.

Comment: Like @John says, there may not be anything you *can* do except suppress the warning.

Comment: How does clearstatcache() work? It's strange the file exists when testing with file_exists() and then it does exist anymore... Several processes trying to delete the same file at the same time maybe?

Comment: Yes, severals processes run this code. It's a big race condition. My problem is that I need to check if I have actually deleted the file, so @ and a check with file_exists() after the unlink may just be fine.

Comment: Maybe there is some OS related "caching"? Try to add a `usleep(100)` after `clearstatcache()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in comment, my need is to be sure I have deleted the file, not to know witch process delete it, so

```
@unlink($filepath);
clearstatcache(TRUE, $filepath);
if(file_exists($filepath)) throw new Exception('file not deleted : ' . $filepath);
```

may be a better way.

Thanks a lot for your help, it's so much easier to think another way to do it with severals comments.

Answer (score 6):

you can try this

```
if(@unlink($path)) {
  echo "Deleted file "; 
}
else{
  echo "File can't be deleted";
}
```

I think it will be pretty fine;

Comment: He says in his question that he doesn't want to use this. It may be the only option, though.